# Data exchange between jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So, I should send data to PHP script (AJAX, jQuery):

```
 - ['item1','item2','item3']
 - action = update
 - uid = 'dsfs112'
```

It should received back:

```
 - ['item2','item3']
 - action = update
 - uid = 'dsfs112'
```

PHP will return my changed array

How the better way to do it?

Comment: You just want PHP to remove `item1` from your array?

Comment: So what's the question? I'm not entirely getting it. Do you already have the code that interchanges the data or do you need it?

Comment: What the question about is? How to send/receive data? How to remove 1st item? Come on, give us a hint.

Comment: Of course I'm asking about the structure of Json object, but not about removing the item in PHP. Not so stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only thing you want to do is to remove the first element of the array from parameters, just use [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) on the array in PHP.

The basic workflow will look like this:

1. Send this data structure using POST (jQuery's `.post()` will do), eg. like that;

   ```
   jQuery.post('my_script.php', {
       'array': ['item1','item2','item3'],
       'action': 'update',
       'uid': 'dsfs112',
   }, function(data){
       // data here is your JSON object
   }, 'json');
   ```
2. On PHP side (within `my_script.php` file probably):

   ```
   <?php
   array_shift($_POST['array']);
   echo json_encode($_POST);
   ```

And this should be all - `data` within your JS success callback should be then of the following structure:

```
{
    'array': ['item2','item3'],
    'action': 'update',
    'uid': 'dsfs112',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON to encode the data. Store the structure as a dictionary (with an array in it) as JSON, send it to PHP. You can then decode the JSON to a PHP structure, change it, re-encode it, and return it back.

These links should be enough to get you going:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/